# Analytic function vs. Continuous function

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that the continuous function $f(z)$ is defined inside the circle $C_r \colon= 
\{z \in {\Bbb C} ；｜z｜<r\}$ s.t. $ r > 1$.

Suppose that $f(z)$ is a non-constant analytic function strictly inside the unit circle.

### Q. Is $f(z)$ automatically analytic inside $C_r$?

Comment: This is a good question. But the answer is no. You can add a non-analytic bump function lying inside $C_r$ but outside the unit circle by choosing the support of the bump function sufficiently small.

Comment: $f(z)=z$ for $|z| <1$, $f(z)=\frac 1 {\overline z}$ for $1\leq |z| <r$